# How do I collect objects being sent in from another function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, javascript-objects

I have a function, let's call it GetData(). I am pulling in data from a query in another function and running an ajax call to populate the data. Once that happens I then send to another function, let's call that PlaceData(). The data is placed together in an object each time it runs through the ajax call in GetData(). I then send each object to PlaceData() and I want to collect these objects in an array in PlaceData() by the push() method but each time it just adds a new array of the current object being sent in so I just get separate objects instead of a collection. How do I get them to collect into one array?

So here is an example of code I am using:

```
function GetData(query) {
    var json = "";
    var api_url = ('https://jsondata.site?conn={conn}&query={query}');
    $.ajax({async: false; url: api_url, method: "GET"}).done(function(data){
        json = JSON.parse(data);
    });
    PlaceData(json);
};

function PlaceData(data) {
    var objCollect = [];
    objCollect.push(data);

    console.log(objCollect);
};
```

I am wanting objCollect[] to keep all objects being passed in but instead I just get a new array with each individual object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a globally scoped variable to store objects. Define `objCollect` out of the functions and it should now hold all the values.

```
var objCollect = [];

function GetData(query) {
    var json = "";
    var api_url = ('https://jsondata.site?conn={conn}&query={query}');
    $.ajax({async: false; url: api_url, method: "GET"}).done(function(data){
        json = JSON.parse(data);
    });
    PlaceData(json);
};

function PlaceData(data) {
    objCollect.push(data);
    console.log(objCollect);
};
```